# SQL : Get yesterdays day with a certain timestamp

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, timestamp

i am trying to get yesterdays date in SQL SERVER with a certain timestamp.

I know how to get yesterdays date in SQL without the timestamp using the following query :

Which gives me every startdate starting from '00:00:00':

```
SELECT se.startdate 
FROM sessions se
WHERE se.startdate >= DATEADD(day, -1, CAST(GETDATE() AS date))
```

Instead I want to get the yesterdays date with a certain timestamp.
For this example every startdate starting from '06:00:00'(AM). Like shown below:

```
 SELECT se.startdate 
    FROM sessions se
    WHERE se.startdate >= '05-09-2022 06:00:00'
```

If I do it the way it was shown in the second example I would have to change the day manually, which would obviously repetitive.

Is there a way to combine the first example with second one so that we get always yesterdays date at
'06:00:00' ?
(OR ANY GIVEN TIME )

Comment: Add 6 hours with DATEADD(hour,6..)

Answer (score 1):

Might as well add another solution, `DATETIMEFROMPARTS`:

```
DECLARE @Yesterday date = DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE());
SELECT DATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@Yesterday),MONTH(@Yesterday),DAY(@Yesterday),6,0,0,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

For example 06:20:40 of the previous day:

```
select DATEADD(second, (6 * 60 + 20 ) * 60 + 40, cast(DATEADD(day, -1, cast(GETDATE() AS date)) as datetime)) t
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it this way:

```
SELECT DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 1, GETDATE()), '06:00:00')
```